# Code to assign label B if label A is assigned by user

Tags: gmail

Employer uses gmail and has changed policy to delete all emails that do not contain the label "DONOTDELETE" after 60 days.  This being done so only important emails are kept.  All important emails are assigned a label already by user.  Is there a way to assign a label of "DONOTDELETE" to all emails at the time a user assigns another label.

This is after email receipt, so Filter of incoming mail will not work at least the way it is intended.  I tried to create a Search criteria based on a single label being contained in an email and use that to Create filter, but Gmail warned me that wouldn't work and it wouldn't work after I stored that filter.  The problem being that filters only work on incoming mail, not on already received mail.  I am not too familiar with Scripts and the like, but if that is the only fix, I am open to it.

I tried storing a filter using Search criteria in Gmail and Create filter icon.